# Hide column in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, hidden-field

I want to hide the value of column in table, the data of table is bind from database

This is my html code

```
<table id="datatable-responsive" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">                                                                          
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th id="th_id_event">Id Event Category</th>
      <th>Event Category</th>
      <th>Description</th>
   </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <% objLOV.forEach(function (lov) { %>
  <tr onclick="callme(this)">
    <td id="td_id_event">
       <%= lov.id %>
    </td>
    <td>
       <%= lov.event_category %>
    </td>
    <td>
       <%= lov.description %>
    </td>
 </tr>
<% }) %>
</tbody>
</table>
```

`<% objLOV.forEach(function (lov) { %>` is to get data from database

I have tried like this, but the only first column first row get hide, I want hide all the value of the column id

```
window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("td_id_event").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("th_id_event").style.display = "none";
   };
```

[my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ccdl.png)

[my table after i tried to disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVGpf.png)

can anyone help me? thank you..

Comment: Don' use Id, use class instead of Id

Comment: thank you.. @NitinDhomse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only validly have one element with a given id so attempting to reference multiple elements with the same id is unlikely to work. You could use a class for the element instead i.e. replace

```
<td id="td_id_event"
```

with

```
<td class="id_event"
```

and then use

```
window.onload = function () {
    var ids = document.getElementsByClassName("id_event");
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        ids[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: may i ask? i use datatable, and when i click next to show the next data, why the value of the column are not hidden @Nick

Comment: Perhaps because you are not reloading the window? The function only runs when the window is loaded. You should probably ask a new question and supply as much information as you can (e.g. what does clicking next do exactly)?